# Low Text Resolution/Text isn't clear on Image in Python Pillow/PIL Library

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, image-manipulation

I am a beginner in Pillow. Basically, I am doing some basic image manipulation task but when I add text to an Image, the **text resolution gets break**.

*Below is my code and image attached.*

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

text = 'Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. \nGood programmers write code that humans can understand.'
font = ImageFont.truetype('Poppins-Bold.ttf', 15 )
im = Image.open("quotes-background.png")
d1 = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
d1.text((60 , 200), text.title(), fill='yellow', font=font)
im.save('quotes.png')
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVThL.png)

Comment: Please clarify what you feel is broken. The text looks pretty reasonable to me.

Comment: If you zoom it you will find it broken. However, in mobile devices it looks fine, but on my laptop it seems more of a low resolution text not smooth enough.